# Ember data createRecord creates multiple records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I inspect Data in ember inspector I see multiple record one with id(int) and one without id(null).

Using ember 2.9.1

```
save: function(){
  var title = this.get('title');
  this.store.createRecord('post',{ title:title }).save();
  this.setProperties({ title:''});
  this.transitionToRoute('posts');
}
```

Node Backend

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  post.create({
    title: req.body.data.attributes.title
  }).then(function () {
    res.set('Content-Type','application/vnd.api+json');
    return res.send({
      "msg": "post created successfully",
      data:null
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return res.status(201).send({
  data:{
    type:'post',
    attributes:{
      id:post.id,
      name:post.title
    }
  }
});
```

The following code works properly.This is a known [issue](http://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4421) in ember data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised to see a post in the data store with an id from this operation.  You should be returning (assuming a RestAdapter)

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  post.create({
    title: req.body.data.attributes.title
  }).then(function (post) {
    res.set('Content-Type','application/vnd.api+json');
    return res.status(201).json(post);
  });
});
```

This will return the created post record that contains the id, which in turn will update the store appropriately.

I suspect the null id is from the current save, and the record with an id is from a previous save?

Comment: still the same issue.Not working.I think this is a known issue https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4421

Comment: Ah, interesting.  In which case you should be able to work around as covered in that issue by this.store.createRecord('post',{ title:title }).save().then(() => {
  this.setProperties({ title:''});
  this.transitionToRoute('posts'); }

Comment: Kind of surprised this answer didn't work though, as it would return the model with the id.  Obviously it's not JSONAPI, but as stated, should work with the RestAdapter.